# Navegador Chrome x IE Wordpress

Tags: php, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho alguns sites no mesmo servidor com wordpress no qual aparecem com erro de carregamento de certas imagens, recentemente eu alterei uma flag no chrome pois alguns sites como o facebook não estavam carregando acentos , após alterar a flag de renderização de caracteres especiais eu também instalei um pacote de font-family no chrome, não sei se pode ter sido isso então surgiu tal erro, não gostaria de reinstalar o navegador pois teria que alterar novamente as flags para optimização, como posso proceder?

Comment: Qual é a font que estás a utilizar? podes mostrar como está o CSS desses icons?

Comment: Aqui está funcionando direito no chrome, por isso deve ser mesmo alguma configuração do seu chrome.

Comment: Tem certeza que são imagens ou são ícones usando fontes personalizadas? Você fala em imagens e fala em pacotes de fontes...

Comment: foi mal são fontes mas o erro persiste , não tenho ideia como arrumar as configurações do chrome para voltarem em padrão acredito que elas se vincularam a minha conta assim que entro com meu login no chrome ele absorve os mesmos erros.. alguem tem ideia do que fazer?

Comment: Descobri outro erro, offline o site carrega no chrome com as fontes certinhas, já depois que faço o upload o erro se inicia, o engraçado e menos pior é que só está acontecendo no meu chrome, fiz o teste em outro pc com outro chrome com outro usuário e pegou tranquilo

Comment: OBS.. já redefini as flags por padrão e o mesmo erro, será macumba?